# Finding a $3\times3$ matrix such that $2A = A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do I find a $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ such that $2A = A^T$? Multiplying by the inverse has not helped.

Comment: Try $A=0.~~~~~$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**.  If $2A=A^T$, then taking the transpose gives
$$2A^T=A$$
and substituting gives
$$4A=A\ .$$
Can you find a solution - even better, **all** solutions of this equation?

Answer (score 2):

$A=\left(\begin{array}{c}a & b& c\\d& e & f\\g&h&i\end{array}\right)$

$2A=\left(\begin{array}{c}2a & 2b& 2c\\2d& 2e & 2f\\2g&2h&2i\end{array}\right)$

$A=\left(\begin{array}{c}a & d& g\\b& e & h\\c&f&i\end{array}\right)$ so you get the system
$\begin{cases} 2a=a\\d=2b\\g=2c\\b=2d\\e=2e\\h=2f\\c=2g\\f=2h\\i=2i\end{cases}$ which gives you that all the elements are $0$.

In a shorter form, it gives you that $a_{ij}=2a_{ji}$ and $a_{ji}=2a_{ij}$ which implies that $a_{ii}=0$ and $a_{ij}=4a_{ij}\Rightarrow 3a_{ij}=0$ for $i\neq j$ all the entries are $0$, assuming of course you work in a ring of characteristic $\neq 3$., like $\mathbb{Q, R, Z}$ etc. If you work for example in $\mathbb Z_3$ you get also other solutions.